# how to capture user input in kendo autocomplete angular

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, autocomplete, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Currently i have created a kendo angular autocomplete component with server filtering option

my html is

```
<input kendo-auto-complete
    k-placeholder="'Select customer'"
    k-filter="'startswith'"
    k-data-text-field="'name'"
    k-data-value-field="'value'"
    k-auto-bind="false"
    k-data-source="customerLookup"
    k-min-length="3"/>
```

my script is

```
$scope.customerLookup = {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://localhost/api/customerData?type=validCustomer",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        };
```

When I input text in my auto complete, the following call is getting happen

http://localhost/api/customerData?type=valiCustomer&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24filter=startswith(tolower(name)%2C'bella')

input text here is: bella

how can i capture the input text in my server side, so i can filter my output in server side

by using following model i can able capture the type in the URL

```
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public LookupTypes Type { get; set; }
```

similarly how can i capture the text typed by user?

helps much appreciated

Comment: cant you append the input value of text box to your URL http://localhost/api/customerData?type=valiCustomer&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24filter=startswith(tolower(name)%2C'bella')

Comment: I'm not able to get the input text from kendo autocomplete

Comment: use something like $('#id').val()

Comment: do we have any option in kendo itself?

Comment: it can be like $("#id").data("kendoAutoComplete*").val()

Comment: @Spark I'm looking for solution using kendo module